# How to display multiple images for django model

Tags: html, django, image, django-models, web-deployment

Here is my image model, that I tied to the model Product

```
class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=20)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is the view that I am using to try and display the images
    def category(request, category_id):
        categories = Category.objects.all()
        images = Image.objects.all()
        products = Product.objects.all()
        try:
            category = Category.objects.get(id=category_id)
        except Category.DoesNotExist:
            category = None;

```
    template = loader.get_template('index.html')
    context = {
        'category': category,
        'categories': categories,
        'images': images,
        'products': products
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))
```

and here is the html

```
 {% for image in images %}
            <a href="#" class="image"><img src="{{ image.url }}"></a>
 {% endfor %}
```

I know this definitely wouldn't work,but atleast this code displays the page instead of an error so i have been using it, can anyone please point me in the right direction to dipslay each image associated with each product. 
Thank you!

Comment: you want to display all products and their respective images

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: did you set media url and media root in settings.py like this
MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploads/')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
  {% for product in products%}
  <p> {{product.name}}  </p>
    {% for simage in product.image_set.all %}
      {% if simage.image%}
        <a href="#" class="image"><img src="{{ simage.image.url }}"></a>
      {% endif %} 
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: That was my first attempt, i tried it again, doesn't cause any errors but the images do not get displayed.

Comment: although rather than {%for product in products%} i do {% for product in category.product_set.all %} since i display products associated with a model category which basically functions the same as the image model

Comment: try {simage.image.url }

Comment: I get the error "The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it", this was my initial error when i first tried this.

Comment: try {% if simage.image% }  <a>show Image </a> {%end if%}

Comment: may be for some products image is not available and its throwing error so try above if condition and check   (CODE UPDATED)

Comment: Holy crap it worked perfectly, Thank you! didnt know that was what i was missing.

Comment: As i said product without images were throwing error but if condition will take care of that , let me know if any issue else accept the answer so it can be marked as closed